# É possível aplicar transparência em gradiente?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber se é possível tornar uma imagem de fundo transparente em uma escala gradiente utilizando HTML, CSS ou JavaScript.

[Imagem de como está](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCreJ.jpg)

Gostaria de aplicar a transparência na imagem superior. No lugar deste gradiente preto, aplicar a transparência para que seja visível essa imagem geométrica que está de fundo.

A imagem que eu gostaria de aplicar a transparência está inserida com o seguinte código CSS:

```
.logo-container {
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%), url(../img/logo_bg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
```

Answer (score -2):

Usa o "opacity: 1;" onde 1 é não-transparente e 0 é totalmente transparente.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).